How Does India Prevent Sharing Sensitive Information Between the U.S. and Russia Under Separate Strategic Agreements?
India has entered into several strategic agreements with both the United States and Russia, involving the sharing of sensitive information, technology, and intelligence. Some key agreements include:

Communications Compatibility and Security Agreement (COMCASA) with the U.S., which facilitates secure communications and the exchange of classified information.

General Security of Military Information Agreement (GSOMIA) with the U.S., aimed at protecting shared military information.

Treaty on Military-Technical Cooperation with Russia, which covers the transfer of defense technology and technical cooperation. India and Russia have also jointly developed missiles and worked on other areas where sensitive information would have been shared.


Given the geopolitical rivalry between the U.S. and Russia, what measures are in place to ensure that India does not inadvertently or intentionally share classified information or sensitive technology from one partner with the other? What measures build trust so that these countries feel comfortable signing such agreements with India?
For example, while sharing intelligence on regional threats or conducting joint military exercises, what safeguards ensure that classified information obtained from the U.S. under COMCASA does not get mixed with the data shared with Russia by India under military cooperation treaties?

I suspect no important information is actually shared. Remember that only a small fraction of classified documents actually contain anything important, as evidenced by Wikileaks and declassified historical archives. So you could probably share 95% of your data and still not share anything important.

I am unsure how much the general public and press will be appraised of the specifics.  However, it is not that far fetched of a question:  India uses both Russian and US heavy weapons.  A quick look-see at the gear of one by the technical support team of the other on a base would probably not be appreciated by those getting snooped on.  Ditto maintenance and operation manuals.  The military is one domain where classifying is probably the right thing to do most of the time.

Prior precedent: Turkey, Russia and the F-35
Turkey is a part of NATO and was originally scheduled to receive its first F-35 fighter jets around 2019. But the U.S. kicked them out of the program as a response to Turkey purchasing the S-400 missile defence system from Russia, which Ankara was quite upset about:

Ankara has censured the U.S.' decision to remove Turkish partners from the $428 billion F-35 stealth fighter jet program over the country's purchase of S-400 surface-to-air-missile system from Russia. "This unilateral step is incompatible with the spirit of alliance and does not rely on any legitimate justification," the Foreign Ministry said in a statement, rejecting Washington's claim that Turkey's purchase of the S-400 system would weaken the F-35 program.

This was a last-minute decision as the aircraft was about to be shipped to Turkey right as the sanctions kicked in:

The Pentagon will acquire eight F-35A jets previously bound for Turkey, plus six more F-35As under an $861.7 million contract announced by the Pentagon on July 20.
<. . .>
Turkey once planned to buy 100 or more F-35s, which would have made it among the largest F-35 operators. But when Turkey opted to buy the Russian S-400 air defense system, the remaining F-35 partners ejected Turkey from the program. U.S. and allied officials said at the time the S-400 was “incompatible” with operating the Lightning II. Russian technicians operating in close proximity to the F-35 would have been able to glean secrets of its stealthy characteristics, the U.S. said.

India has likewise acquired the S-400 and this was cited as one reason they’ve so far been unable to purchase more advanced technology from the U.S.:

In 2018, India had signed an agreement worth $5.43 billion for five S-400 defense systems with Russia. The delivery was expected to begin toward the end of 2020, whereas the first delivery took place in December 2021. Since China and Turkey’s S-400 deal resulted in the CAATSA sanctions, it was expected that the U.S. would follow the same procedures for India too. However, due to geopolitical and geostrategic reasons, India presumably might receive a sanction waiver under a clause in the fiscal year 2019 National Defense Authorization Act (NDAA) that allows the U.S. president to issue a waiver to CAATSA sanctions. Nonetheless, the issue of granting an exemption remained ambiguous during the administration of former U.S. President Donald Trump. However, members of the U.S. Senate, U.S.-India Business Council and some think tanks argue that U.S. President Joe Biden’s possible CAATSA sanctions against India will negatively affect the strategic partnership between the two countries.

As mentioned in the article there’s talks of making an exception to sell India the (less capable) F-21 jet with some F-35 tech but as of 2024 the deal is still pending. The same restrictions presumably apply to other advanced technology the Russians might want to steal.
Not all secrets are equally important
The U.S. obviously doesn’t want to hand military secrets to Russia on a silver plate but only a small fraction of classified information could actually make a difference in future proxy wars. In the case of a direct NATO-Russia war it’s likely that only NCBMs will matter, along with missile defense systems capable if intercepting an ICBM. India (as per public information) has not received either.

Well, India is reciprocating by selling Oniks-derived missiles (BrahMos) to US ally Philippines. ("The name BrahMos is a portmanteau formed from the names of two rivers, the Brahmaputra of India and the Moskva of Russia.")

There's some misinformation here - The US never offered India the F35, but dangled a variation of it (some fusion of F21 + F35, without tech transfer) only if we didn't buy the S-400 from the Russians. Also, the Indian Air Force was not at all interested in acquiring the F35. In general, India avoids buying arms from America as they only offer us expensive, outdated technology, that come with too many conditions which allow the Americans to interfere in our military operations.

@sfxedit that’s my point exactly! The U.S. doesn’t sell India their very best tech, partially due to their alliance with Russia. And likely never will, at least until India is fully aligned with NATO interests.

@sfxedit clarified that only the F-21 will be sold, thanks.

But India doesn't have an alliance with Russia. Just as India didn't have an alliance with the west when they were supplying us nuclear technology in the 50's. The bedrock of our foreign policy is non-alignment - not being in a military alliance, against any particular nation - backed by a strong military to ensure we have political space to pursue an independent foreign policy. Russia has learnt to be comfortable with that national characteristic of ours, and even come to respect it. So they trust us with even technologies like cryogenic engines and nuclear submarines, and even tech transfer.

The problem with the Anglo-Americans is that they still can't decide whether to trust us. In some ways, the US military-industrial complex is also a factor in this. India is one of the world's largest arms buyer. But it has also, over the decades been building a capable nuclear, space and defence industry and becoming more self-reliant. Thus, it has now pivoted to buying arms that involve tech transfer or are jointly developed. The US military-industrial doesn't like this as a country becoming self-reliant means it loses a customer, and worse, could be helping create a potential rival.

@sfxedit this is a nice explanation of India’s public declarations and grievances against other states but is hardly relevant to what OP is asking, which is what policies are adapted by American leaders. Indian citizens might genuinely believe that their country is peaceful and not allied with anyone but domestic beliefs are ~irrelevant to foreign actors.

@sfxedit overall the U.S. couldn’t care less about the Indian military market. India never bought more than ~$1B in weapons per year from America, which is a laughable sum in the Pentagons overall budget. For comparison the U.S. spent around $20 billion per year on air conditioning alone in Afghanistan and Iraq back in 2011. They also don’t worry about India becoming a serious rival as this would be a great opportunity to damage China and force them to spend resources on countering India.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

As for S-400, it doesn't look like a super smart buy ATM. The were multiple videos coming out of the Russia-Ukraine war where an S-300/400 battery was overwhelmed by ATACMS, overflown by Storm Shadows etc. Radom example that was easy to find https://www.reddit.com/r/CombatFootage/comments/1fnhrd1/additional_and_higherquality_footage_of_the/

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever presumably its garbage but still better than whatever India can build locally or get their hands on internationally. Or could be that corruption or poor planning is involved. All of this stuff is classified so its hard to scrutinize the Indian officials decisions, which is also part of the reason why intelligence services love classifying as much as they can - not just in India but all over the world. Incompetence and corruption love staying in the shadows.
